# an alternative to floating references to GObject

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, gobject

I am reading a [lecture on GTK+ memory management](http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/course_materials/csci493.70/lecture_notes/GTK_memory_mngmt.pdf), chapter "Objects Descending from `GInitiallyUnown`ed." The concept of floating references was introduced so we can write code

```
container = create_container();
container_add_child(container, create_child());
```

instead of

```
Child *child;
container = create_container();
child = create_child();
container_add_child(container, child);
g_object_unref(child);
```

I immediately realized that the same can be achieved as follows. There is a function `container_add_child_move_ownership`. `container_add_child` is superfluous. It is assumed that `container_add_child_move_ownership(container, child)` move ownership from the caller to `container`, so `container_add_child_move_ownership` does not change reference count. Therefore, the following example is correct.

```
void f(Container *container) {
    container_add_child_move_ownership(container, create_child());
}
```

Either 0) my solution has a flaw I do not see, or 1) the concept of floating references is a bad design decision. Which is true?

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is really not a good way to discuss this with the API designers of GObject and the G* platform; you probably want to ask on the [gtk-devel](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gtk-devel-list) mailing list instead.

Yes, floating references are just a fancy way to do ownership transfer.

The issue with a "move ownership" API approach is that there were no well defined type semantics for pointer ownership. You simply do not know — unless you name your API awkwardly like `container_add_with_ownership_transfer()` — beforehand. Additionally, it would imply that some API works with ownership transfer, but it cannot be discovered through type inspection. This is *especially* critical for language bindings, because they need to know the ownership transfer rules.

In recent times, GObject gained additional annotations for introspection purposes, but of course it's way too late to modify the API and type system.

Answer (score 0):

> 0. my solution has a flaw I do not see

The problem with your solution is that you have to make two functions:

- container_add_child.
- container_add_child_move_ownership.

Consider a case when you don't want to move ownership. In this case you have two options:

1. Increase reference count of the object before moving it into a function:

`container_add_child_move_ownership(container, g_object_ref(child))`

2. Add another function that doesn't move ownership:

`container_add_child(container, child)`

With floating reference, you have just one function that works for both cases.

> 1. the concept of floating references is a bad design decision.

Personally for me, yes, it is bad design. Your solution with moving ownership is more clear than the solution with floating references, even if you have to make two functions (but I would make short name for the moving function like `container_add_child_mv`).

With floating references you have to think [which function to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66274212/5447906) `g_object_ref_sink` or just `g_object_ref`. With floating references you have to [handle potentially floating parameters carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66274835/5447906).

Even the GLib documentation has a [note](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#floating-ref) about the floating references:

***Note**: Floating references are a C convenience API and should not be used in modern GObject code. Language bindings in particular find the concept highly problematic, as floating references are not identifiable through annotations, and neither are deviations from the floating reference behavior, like types that inherit from GInitiallyUnowned and still return a full reference from g_object_new().*