# Should we always use g_object_ref_sink instead of g_object_ref?

Tags: glib, gobject

There are two functions in GLib that work with the reference counting of the GObject objects:

- `g_object_ref` increases reference count of the object, doesn't handle floating references.
- `g_object_ref_sink` increases reference count of the object or just removes *floating* flag from the object if the reference is floating.

Since we don't know if the object is floating or not, we should always use `g_object_ref_sink`, shouldn't we? If I am wrong, when should we use `g_object_ref` and when should we use `g_object_ref_sink`? Should we use `g_object_ref_sink` only for `GInitiallyUnowned` objects?

Answer (score 1):

You should generally know the type of an object you’re handling (i.e. pointers typically have more specific types than `GObject*`), so you’ll know if it’s potentially floating or not. GObject-based APIs which use floating references are documented as using them. Anything which isn’t documented as using floating references, doesn’t.