# How to handle floating reference parameters in GLib properly?

Tags: glib, gobject

There are floating reference objects in GLib.

```
container = create_container();
container_add_child(container, create_child());
```

In this example the `create_child` function creates *floating* object that is not owned by anybody. The `container_add_child` function takes ownership of the object and becomes the only owner of the object. When it disowns the object, the object is freed.

But what if the `container_add_child` function didn't take ownership of the object? In this case we would get a memory leak. Yes, the object is not owned by anybody, but it still exists in memory and no one frees memory of the object.

What if we write a function that takes such object as a parameter.

```
void handle_object(gpointer object)
{
    g_object_ref_sink(object);
    
    // Doing something with object
    
    g_object_unref(object);
}
```

Do we have to add `g_object_ref_sink` / `g_object_unref` to every function that takes potentially floating reference object as a parameter? If we remove these lines, then someone may make such call: `handle_object(create_child())` and we will get a memory leak. The object will be "floating" in memory forever.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have to add `g_object_ref_sink` / `g_object_unref` to every function that takes potentially floating reference object as a parameter?

Yes, that’s one of the reasons why building an API around floating references is a pain. Better to not use them and use explicit [ownership transfer annotations](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GObjectIntrospection/Annotations) (`(transfer none)` or `(transfer full)`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have to add g_object_ref_sink / g_object_unref to every function that takes potentially floating reference object as a parameter? If we remove these lines, then someone may make such call: handle_object(create_child()) and we will get a memory leak. The object will be "floating" in memory forever.

*A wise man's question contains half the answer.*
It's a good idea to add ref/unref to any object you use. It may not be the case in single-threaded app or GUI method, where you can be 100% sure that nobody even has the possibility to destroy an object. But in a multi-threaded apps object can be unrefed in any moment, and that will lead to invalidation of that object.

However, the need of two separate methods (`ref_sink` and `ref`) is not clear to me after 5 years of working with GTK:)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer my question.

> Do we have to add g_object_ref_sink / g_object_unref to every function that takes potentially floating reference object as a parameter?

I would say, do not pass *"potentially"* floating references to functions that don't expect them. A floating reference is special. You can't access object referenced by floating reference because you **don't own it** (no one owns it). Before using such objects you must call `g_object_ref_sink` to get ownership. Or pass the reference to function that takes ownership (but after calling such function you still can't use the object because you still don't own it).

So, if function assumes that you own the object, do not pass floating reference to it. In this case you don't have to add `g_object_ref_sink` / `g_object_unref` to such functions.

If, for some reasons, function takes "potentially" floating reference, then, yes, you have to add `g_object_ref_sink` / `g_object_unref` to it. But if the function don't store the reference somewhere to use it later then this function is probably bad designed. If the function uses the object only locally (only during the call), then do not add `g_object_ref_sink` / `g_object_unref` to it, and do not pass floating references to it. If the function saves the reference for later usage, then `g_object_ref_sink` must be added to it to get ownership. But in this case there will be not `g_object_unref` call in this function, because someone is going to use the reference later, after the function exits.

So I would say, adding a pair of `g_object_ref_sink` and `g_object_unref` to function is not ok. Adding just `g_object_ref_sink` for getting ownership to use the reference later after the function exits, is ok.

Yes, this makes things difficult because you must always care about whether the reference is floating or whether it is not. That's why I personally do not like the floating reference idea. But it also makes things easier in cases like adding new objects to containers.